# r summary and geometric mean

Tags: r, summary

I am using the r `summary` function to estimate data summaries for predictors in my dataset.

```
 data("TitanicSurvival")
 s <- summary(age ~ sex + survived, TitanicSurvival)
 plot(s, main ='', subtitles=FALSE)
```

Right now the default option, I think is set to display "arithmetic mean". How can I change this so that the `summary` function will estimate summaries based on **geometric mean** and not arithmetic mean. Thanks.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in the code you need to include loading of the packages you use! I do that below. First, a function for the geometric mean:

```r
gmean <- function(x) exp(mean(log(x)))
```

Then the solution:

```r
library(Hmisc)
library(carData)
data("TitanicSurvival")
s <- summary(age ~ sex + survived, 
             TitanicSurvival, fun=gmean)
plot(s, main ='', subtitles=FALSE)
```